# How to pass a context path to a curl post

Tags: json, curl, dynamic, path

I'm trying to invoke a service as below to create an object using Json template as a input to the service and the service require the following {Dynamicvalue} to be passed . Can someone please help ?

```
Dynamicvalue=$1
curl -k --silent -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header "$AUTH_HEADER_VALUE" \
-d @"$SLOCAL_FILE" "https://test.com/${1:?}/testapi"
```

I'm using Shell Script .

Dynamicvalue is an Appname that keeps changing .

I'm running the script by passing the Value for Dynamicvalue as follows

```
./testscript.sh invest_domain # Invest_domain is the appname
```

once I run the script `$AUTH_HEADER_VALUE` and `$SLOCAL_FILE` are loaded correctly except for the argument that I'm passing and I get the below error displayed on the screen

```
  Calling testapi service.
```

testscript.sh: line 255: 1: parameter null or not set

But the value is set as follows Dynamicvalue=$1

Comment: You should describe more what should be `{Dynamicvalue}` and how it's generated

Comment: It's basically an application name that keeps changing for which I will be creating an object in the UI by invoking the above service.

Comment: If you want to comment a command line, use `#` prefix !

Comment: And you missed a `$` in the url, edited

Comment: Sorry I missed the $ here but It's there in the script and the comments were just for your understanding.

Comment: So if it's for understanding, use `# prefix` (like every shell scripts)

Comment: IT WORKED !!! Thank you so very much Gilles :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a shell variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

dynamicvalue="$1"
AUTH_HEADER_VALUE='...'
LOCAL_FILE='...'

curl -k --silent -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header "$AUTH_HEADER_VALUE" \
-d @"$SLOCAL_FILE" "https://test.com/${dynamicvalue:?}/testapi"
```

### Usage

```
./script appName
```

Comment: Thank you Gilles.

Comment: I have tried this but I get this error as soon as I run the script
{
  "responseType": "error",
  "status": 500,
  "data": [
    {
      "message": "java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: I did and tested it.

Comment: Try `bash -x script appName` to debug

Comment: AUTH_HEADER_VALUE='...'
LOCAL_FILE='...' headers got loaded as expected but the URL is changed to this" https://test.com/{}/testapi " with the following error
An error occured. Please see the service response below.
+ printf '{
  "responseType": "error",
  "status": 500,
  "data": [
    {
      "message": "java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException"
    }
  ]
}'
{
  "responseType": "error",
  "status": 500,
  "data": [
    {
      "message": "java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException"
    }
  ]
}+ printf '\nExiting.\n'

Comment: You seems to not pass the argument to the shell script. Post edited, can you try again ? If error, don't add a comment but edit your original post with new informations